# Kubernetes :Validation Error(Deployment.spec.template.spec.container[0]): unknown field "ConfigMapref" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am doing my first deployment in Kubernetes and I've hosted my API in my namespace and it's up and running. So I tried to connect my API with MongoDB. Added my database details in ConfigMaps via Rancher.

I tried to invoke the DB in my deployment YAML file but got an error stating `Unknown Field - ConfigMapref`

Below is my deployment YAML file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myfistproject
  namespace: Owncloud
spec
  replicas: 2
  selector:
   matchLables:
    app: myfirstproject
    version: 1.0.0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myfirstproject
        version: 1.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
         - name: myfirstproject
           image: **my image repo location**
           imagePullPolicy: always
           ports:
             - containerPort: 80
           configMapRef:
             - name: myfirstprojectdb # This is the name of the config map created via rancher
```

`myfirstprojectdb` ConfigMap will store all the details like the database name, username, password, *etc.*

On executing the pipeline I get the below error.

How do I need to refer my config map in deployment yaml?

```
Validation Error(Deployment.spec.template.spec.container[0]): unknown field "ConfigMapref" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container
```

Comment: There are a couple of obvious typos in the YAML file (`labels` vs. `lables`, `ports` without a colon); can you double-check that you've copied this file correctly?  Is `configMapRef:` inside an `envFrom:` block?

Comment: Typo's have been corrected

Comment: Is `configMapRef:` inside an `envFrom:` block?  See the [Pod reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#environment-variables), and also [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data), both in the Kubernetes documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more typos (e.g. missing `:` after `spec` or `Always` should be with capital letter). Also `indentation` should be consistent in the whole `yaml` file - [see yaml indentation and separation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm).

I corrected your yaml so it passes api server's check + added config map reference (considering it contains env variables):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myfistproject
  namespace: Owncloud
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myfirstproject
      version: 1.0.0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myfirstproject
        version: 1.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myfirstproject
          image: **my image repo location**
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: myfirstprojectdb
```

Useful link:

[Configure all key-value pairs in a ConfigMap as container environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables) which is related to this question.